# Function the uses an object relying in two different packages

Tags: java, oop

I have the sama java object TestData in to packages (A & B). I have made a function that processes the object for a standard business functionality.

**CommonFunc.java:**

```
import A.TestData ;
class CommonFunc
{
  ///  .....

    public static TestData processTestData(Date d1, String s1){

        TestData testData = new TestData ();

        /// set some testData  porperties based on d1 and s1
        /// e.g : testData.setInitialDate(d1);

        return testData ;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler has to load the object from one of the packages lets say package (A), so when I expect the data to be returned to a local variable from package (B) I get incompatible type error :

File using B TestData and needs to call the function processTestData:

```
import B.TestData;

// ...

TestData obj = CommonFunc.processTestData(new Date(), "test");

// ...
```

Is there a way to overcome this problem keeping a common function for both?

Comment: Why do you have two different `TestData` classes?

Comment: It is because it has been automatically generated from 2 different XSDs that appear to have similar elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to overcome this problem keeping a common function for both?

No and yes. On the general case, you cannot.

But you can, **IFF** you can make the two classes adopt the same interface, with the common methods declared in the same interface. See below, with apologies for the change in the class names:

```
interface C {
  public Date getA();
  public void setA(Date a);

}
interface C_Factory <X extends C> {
  X createInstance();
}

class C1 implements C {
  Date a;
  int b;

  public C1() {
    super();
  }

  public Date getA() { return a;  }
  public void setA(Date a) {  this.a = a;  }


  public int getB() { return b; }
  public void setB(int b) {  this.b = b;  }
}

class C2 implements C {
  Date a;
  float b;

  public C2() {
    super();
  }

  public Date getA() { return a;  }
  public void setA(Date a) {  this.a = a; }


  public float getB() { return b; }
  public void setB(float b) {  this.b = b;  }
}

public class CommonFunc {
  // You need this extra param to create instances----
  //                                                 V
  static <X extends C> X doSomething(Date d, Class<X> clazz)
  throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
  // You'll have to accept those exceptions as well
  {
    // the next statement uses clazz as a factory for new X instances
    // As such, you can abstract the method further and use
    // a custom Factory class instead.
    X toret=clazz.newInstance();
    toret.setA(d);
    // something else

    return toret;
  }

  // A custom factory variant of the above
  static <X extends C> X doSomething(Date d, C_Factory<X> factory)
  {
    X toret=factory.createInstance();
    toret.setA(d);
    // something else

    return toret;
  }

  static public void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      C1 c1=doSomething(new Date(), C1.class);
      C2 c2=doSomething(new Date(), C2.class);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      // Should not happen
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how it is possible in the above example you have posted, The best way out is to make the TestData an interface and have implementations in 2 packages. Then, to decide whether to return A TestDataImpl or B TestDataImpl, take another parameter in the processData, for simplicity, let us say a boolean. Based on true or false instantiate A TestDataImpl or B TestDataImpl and return the same. Where the return type of processData is the interface type

This is probably would be the most straightforward way of reusing the processData method.